# Piping A Grunt task output to another task input?

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I want to minify my Handlebars HTML templates before compiling them. I was wondering is it possible to pipe the output of **grunt-contrib-htmlmin** as input to **grunt-contrib-handlebars** without making an intermediate file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grunt by design does not support piping. Take a look at [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), where piping is the main concept.